# Use EditorFor for model's base class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a more difficult structure of base/derived classes in my app, but to keep it easier, let's assume an easy example of a model:

```
public class Base
{
   public string BaseProp { get; set; }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
   public string DerivedProp { get; set; }
}
```

I want to make EditorTemplates for these classes, the `Base.cshtml` is easy:

```
@model Base

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.BaseProp)
```

But in the `Derived.cshtml`, I would suppose I'm able to call EditorFor on the base class, something like this:

```
@model Derived

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DerivedProp)

//This throws an exception in a browser
@Html.EditorFor(model => (Base)model)

//This is without an exception, 
//but nothing happens, there are no fields of base class in the page
@{
    var baseObj = (Base)Model;
    @Html.EditorFor(_ => baseObj)
}
```

Is there a way, how to call the EditorTemplate of base class correctly? I've found just [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245851/editorfor-isnt-working-on-derived-type) 6 years old topic, but it provides just a workaround using a Partial in custom helper instead of EditorFor, which is still not an ideal solution. Don't we have a better straightforward way in newer versions of ASP?